# Trying to prove by induction that a set has 2**n subsets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Ok, my proof goes as follows:

```
Assume there is a number n part of the Natural numbers
Assume any size of size has 2**n subsets
Assume we have a set S
Then the cardinality of S = n + 1, which is > 0
Then there exists an X part of S
*Partition the subsets of S into those that contain X and those that don't.
Logically, if we are considering all the subsets that don't contain X we are considering all the subsets from S - {X}, which will have (n+1)-1 elements -based on the cardinality of S
Now S-{X} has clearly n elements, 2**n subsets.
```

My problem is I'm stuck here.... how do I prove that the part containing x also has n elements, how can I get that conclusion and then prove it has 2**n subsets, adding both together and getting 2**n+1 for S.

Oh and about the *, I have a question, does the partitioning mean we are creating two subsets containing the other sets, or we are just classifying them in two imaginary groups unrelated to mathematical sets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us consider those subsets of the original set which contain X. They are obtained by taking subsets of the original set that don't contain X and adding X to them, so since there is 2^n subsets that don't contain X, there will be 2^n subsets that contain X (obtained by just adding X to the forementioned 2^n).
I think this should be enough to answer your question.

And partitioning in this sense means we create new sets which are to be sets of specific subsets of the original set, thus subsets of the power set of the original set.

Comment: Ohhh, the problem with proofs is that I omit little details that seem so obvious. This is all I needed.

Answer (score 1):

To create a subset, every element has two choices: either it is in the subset or out of it. It follows that

$|\mathcal P \left({S}\right)|=2^{|S|}$. Here $\mathcal P \left({S}\right)$ denotes the power set of $S$, the set of all subsets of $S$.